# Understanding the Basics of Generics Sorting

Tags: java, sorting, generics

There are a number of question on Stack Overflow about sorting Generics; however, I am interested in sorting Generics in the simplest way: nothing nested. The code I have below is an attempt to sort a generic set - or, list - of elements.

```
List<E> l = new LinkedList<>(arbSet);
Collections.sort(l);
```

`arbSet` is just a set of elements: `Set<E> arbSet`.

Clearly, this is problematic - it shouldn't work. To make sure I know this, Eclipse gives me the following for my attempt to call `.sort`:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List < T >) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List < E >). The inferred type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter < T extends Comparable < ? super T >>

So, I do a bit of documentation consultation, looking at `sort`'s [specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-).

As a result, I attempt to ensure that `sort` knows `E` extends `Comparable`:

The first line now looking like:

```
List<E extends Comparable<? super E>> l = new LinkedSet<>(arbSet);
```

Now, Eclipse states :

> Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

What am I missing? I feel like this is a very basic example and that I am just missing something "palm-to-face" esque. Just to simplify it even further, all `arbSet` elements are elements which implement the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: Where is the type parameter `E` declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Collections.sort()` only if you provide a custom `Comparator` or if the elements you are trying to sort implement the `Comparable` interface. So it depends on what elements are stored in `arbSet`.

For example, if you wanted to create a method that accepts a set, and returns a list with the set elements sorted, you would do something like this:

```
static <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> sortedListFrom(Set<E> set) {
    List<E> l = new LinkedList<>(set);
    Collections.sort(l);
    return l;
}
```

Edit:

If you want to do this inside a constructor you have two options:

1. Declare the type `E` just before the constructor. Of course, this won't do much, since `list` is lost after the constructor finishes.

   ```
   class Test {
       <E extends Comparable<E>> Test(Set<E> arbSet) {
           List<E> list = new LinkedList<>(arbSet);
           Collections.sort(list);
           System.out.println(list);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Declare the type `E` in the class, so you can store the result in a attribute.

   ```
   class Test<E extends Comparable<E>> {
       List<E> list;

       Test(Set<E> arbSet) {
           this.list = new ArrayList<>(arbSet);
           Collections.sort(this.list);
           System.out.println(this.list);
       }
   }
   ```